# How Create Curl Page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I want to animate a widget in a "page curl" fashion like in [this video](https://youtu.be/TIsSGWXiUf8).

There is already a pub.dev package [page_turn](https://pub.dev/packages/page_turn) that does this, but it converts the widget into an image, which I don't want to do.

Is there any other way to create this animation without converting the widget to an image?

Comment: From what I can see in the package source code, it doesn't convert the widget to an image. Do you possibly mean that touch events on your widget don't work? That's because the PageTurn widget is intercepting touch events. Can you clarify if this is the issue?

Comment: It converts it to a image you can see this https://i.ibb.co/n3x7T8y/stack.png

Comment: That's my bad. In that case, what is the specific behavior you want that an image doesn't work for? Are you trying to update the widget while it's being flipped?

Comment: and curl page in package is from RTL and i want the opposite

Comment: Because if I select some text with the image, I cannot, and I do not understand the method I use to turn the page

Comment: You could try modifying the package so that the widget is only an image during the animation and a normal widget otherwise, and make it from LTR. However, there isn't a simple way to do this using a flutter transform since this transition can't be expressed by a transformation matrix. The existing package manually calculates the pixel positions and draws the image.

Comment: @dominicm00 Could it be made with PageView ?

Comment: PageView defines the scrolling physics for position, but it doesn't provide a transform on the widget. Flutter doesn't have any built-in solution for a transform as complex as this.